# Windows 10 lock screen appears every 30 minutes regardless of activity

Tags: laptop, windows-10, toshiba-laptop, lock-screen

System: Toshiba Satellite C75D-A

I usually put my computer into hibernation when not in use, but it seems that every time I do, after resuming, the lock screen appears every 30 minutes regardless of whether it's idle or not. I can be moving the mouse or typing and it still happens. I played around with the lock screen settings and I discovered that it only happens when slideshow mode is on. However, even with slideshow off, the screen still goes blank every 30 minutes until I move the mouse, then it returns to normal. Nothing about this issue makes sense to me because I can't find any settings that are set for 30 minutes. The screen is set to turn off after 10 minutes, sleep is set to 15 minutes (balanced power plan), and screen saver is turned off. I am completely stumped. It's very annoying and I can't find an answer anywhere, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

More details (if it matters):
OS: Windows 10 Home (64-bit)
Display: Secondary monitor (hdmi)
Input: Logitech wireless mouse and keyboard with Unifying USB adapter

Comment: Test with different mouse and keyboard. Scan for viruses or malware.

Comment: I've been getting this issue for ages, and whenever I google it, I get answers (including many from Microsoft customer support) saying to simply increase the idle lock time, or turn off the lock screen entirely. The first suggestion seems irrelevant, and the second is undesirable. What would cause windows to stop registering input for the purpose of determining that the PC is idle?

Comment: I started getting this problem this week. I have set the power plan to never turn off the monitor (or anything else) and set the screen saver to never fire.

Comment: Changing mouse and keyboard has no effect on the problem. Rebooting has no effect on the problem. Virus scan and malware scan turn up nothing.