# Screen goes black exactly every half hour

Tags: windows-10, display, lock-screen

My Windows 10 pro desktop has begun an annoying habit. Every half hour, at exactly :02 or :32, the screen turns off, exactly as if I had left the machine unattended or not touched the keyboard or mouse in a long time. To be clear, this is while I am using the computer -- sometimes in the middle of typing or moving the mouse.

After it goes black, moving the mouse or touching the keyboard then turns it on again, bringing me to the locked screen, where I have to enter my PIN.

The power plan is set to never turn off the monitor. 
The screen saver settings are set to never fire the screen saver.
Changing keyboard and mouse hardware has no effect.
Virus scan turned up nothing.

While typing this, it brought up [Windows 10 lock screen appears every 30 minutes regardless of activity](https://superuser.com/q/1019966/281372) as a possible question match. That question is over two years old, however, and has no answers; and my problem just started last week. So I would appreciate a fresh look at this.

Is there a way I can at least determine what process is locking the screen?

Comment: While I realize this might require an investment of time to try, but does this happen in Safe Mode? The answer could rule out a lot of possible causes.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator -- it's the simplest things that I never think of.  It did not happen in safe mode, even when allowed to run for an hour. And it did not happen after rebooting from safe into normal mode, even after running all night unattended! Thank you for your suggestion, and I'll accept this as answer if you write it as one.

Comment: Just can't believe I let this bother me for 10 days without rebooting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a *lot* of possible causes. You can narrow down what's responsible by running the computer in Safe Mode long enough to see if the behavior is reproduced. If it is not, this indicates there's something running in normal mode that's triggering the problem.  Try disabling programs and non-critical drivers and services one-by-one to see which one is responsible (you can do this with MSConfig, though I prefer SysInternals [Autoruns](http://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe)).

It's also possible that *all* you need is a reboot, though if the problem comes back you'll still want to try turning things off to see who's ultimately to blame.

Comment: It did go away after reboot. I'll keep in mind the one-by-one ideas if it comes back. However, I was hoping there was something I could do to catch it in the act, like [ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). or something. (There probably is, but nobody's ever dug in to figure out exactly what filter to use, because it's not much of a common problem.)

Comment: @RossPresser I'm not sure what you'd be looking for in procmon. My top 2 guesses why you had this problem are 1) A program is *intentionally* triggering monitor turn off, 2) Windows is not resetting the idle timer. Neither would be found via ProcMon (unless you knew which program was doing #1, invalidating the need for ProcMon in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Check below configuration:

1. Control Panel - All Control Panel Items - Power Options – your current power plan and click Change Plan Settings – make sure Turn off the display is configured as Never – click Change advanced power settings – please check “Turn off hard disk after” and “Display”, configured them both to Never and save the change.
2. Right click desktop and select Personalization – Screen timeout settings – change it to Never.
3. Contact hardware supporter/provider and confirm with them about the BIOS – Power relate configuration.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I had done both 1 & 2.